# Filter a report using query string parameters in the URL - not working because of &

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, daxstudio

This is my column name and value below.

ASSET_NAME - mats&service

Below is the dax code i use to get data from table and create a link to filter the my page, but it wont work when value(mats&service) in column(ASSET_NAME) has & in it, the link gets terminated at & like this
https:/app.powerbi.com/?filter/somerandomtextand%20andthesemats
and the filter wont work, can someone help me escape this & so that value is accepted and filtered in my page,

```
RawData =
MAX ('Raw data'[Raw Data])&"?filter=Table/ASSET_NAME eq"&" '"
& MAX ( CurrentData[ASSET_NAME] )&"' and Table/LEVEL1 eq"&" '"
& MAX ( CurrentData[LEVEL])&"' and Table/DOS_NO eq"&" ' "
& MAX ( CurrentData[RULE_NO] )&" ' "
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-url-filters) has a section how to handle [special characters in the values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-url-filters#special-characters-in-values). The `&` character should be replaced with `%26`, so instead of `mats&service` value, try with `mats%26service`.

When concatenating the strings to construct the URL, use [SUBSTITUTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/substitute-function-dax) DAX function (or multiple nested or separate calls to it) to replace the special characters in the values, e.g. like this:

```
Measure = 
    var AssetName1 = MAX(CurrentData[ASSET_NAME])
    var AssetName2 = SUBSTITUTE(AssetName1, "%", "%25")
    var AssetName3 = SUBSTITUTE(AssetName2, "+", "%2B")
    var AssetName4 = SUBSTITUTE(AssetName3, "&", "%26")
    RETURN "?filter=Table/ASSET_NAME eq '" & AssetName4 & "'"
```

Another option is to [add a custom column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-add-custom-column) with "safe" values, which are URL encoded using [Uri.EscapeDataString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/uri-escapedatastring) M function:

```
ASSET_NAME_ENCODED = Uri.EscapeDataString([ASSET_NAME])
```

and use this column when constructing the URL.

[image]

Comment: thanks,but this is a dynamic one,i cant change value in table

Comment: @evanoruvan Of course you can! Either use `Uri.EscapeDataString` to get values, which are safe to be used in the URL, or replace the special characters one by one (starting with `%`!) by calling `SUBSTITUTE` function. I've added examples how you can do this in my answer.